# photo format returned in telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I am using telethon(a library for working with telegram). I can not figure out the output for photos. Can someone tell me how to convert this format to jpg viewer? Thanks

```
\x01\x17(\x91\xef\xa7G\xdaDx\xf6\xff\x00\xf5\xd4\xcbrH\xcf\xc8G\xa8\xff\x00\xf5\xd6la\xe5e\\\x92\t\xab\xe0\x05\x8c\x8c\xec\xe7\x08~\x9dk>g{"\xd4U\xaeL\x97\x06N\x13c\x11\xd4\x0ei%\x96\xe1W\xe4\x84\x13\xfe\xe9\xa8\xec\x14\x0b\xb9H\x1c\x15\xe2\xb4*\x96\xaa\xe2\x94l\xecQ\x13]y`\x98@>\x9bM\x15u\xf3\xb5\xbe\x94S$\xc8\x82\xd6Y\xd9\x19\xbe\xe9\x1ds\xcd>uX\x1b\x0e\xe3\'\x91\xc1\xa2\x8a\x96\x91Wc,\xa7\x8a\xdeWw\x9bp~\x80\x03\xd6\xae\xff\x00i[c;\x8f\xfd\xf3E\x15ih&\xee\xc6\xb6\xa9jP\xe1\xdb\xa7\xf7M\x14Q@\x8f
```

Comment: I think you need to provide some code showing how you got this far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download that image to be able to see it. to do so you could use the `download_media` method like so

`path = client.download_media(messageThatHasTheImage)`

that method will return where the image was saved by default.